# Dynamcially split/delimite column into multiple columns Vertically using sql server

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-server-2012

I need to split a table where ID field is repeated over multiple times. Semicolon would serve as a delimiter. This is a dynamic data set where 'built' column is dynamic. Builder have dynamic years of experience so we cannot use fixed position delimiter. Here is the sample data.

```
---- Sample data
    CREATE TABLE TEST1
    (
        ID varchar(20), 
        FIELD varchar(max)
    );

    INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID, FIELD)
    VALUES 
    ('ERIC','BUILT;1995/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;OZ C1/BUILT;2010/PROPERTY;Condo/TYPE;F4/BUILT;2010/PROPERTY;Condo/TYPE;F9/'),
    ('ERIC','BUILT;1996/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;OZ C1/'),
    ('ERIC','BUILT;1997/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;OZ C1/'),
    ('ERIC','BUILT;2011/PROPERTY;Condo/TYPE;F4/BUILT;2015/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;C5/');
```

This is the End result I am aiming for With ID, Built, Property and type as column headers and data presented vertically.

```
ID      BUILT   PROPERTY    TYPE
--------------------------------
ERIC    1995    House       OZ C1
ERIC    2010    Condo       F4
ERIC    2010    Condo       F9
ERIC    1996    House       OZ C1
ERIC    1997    House       OZ C1
ERIC    2011    Condo       F4
ERIC    2015    House       C5
```

I am aware of the following way to split into columns. However this is not what I require. This will split data horizontally and I need it vertical.

```
WITH Split_Fields (ID, xmlfields)
AS
(
    SELECT ID ,
    CONVERT(XML,'<Fields><field>'  
    + REPLACE(name,'.', '</field><field>') + '</field></Fields>') AS xmlfields
      FROM TEST1
)

SELECT ID      
 ,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[1]';'varchar(100)') AS Field1    
 ,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[2]';'varchar(100)') AS Field2
,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[3]';'varchar(100)') AS Field3    
 ,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[4]';'varchar(100)') AS Field4
,xmlfields.value('/Fields[1]/field[5]';'varchar(100)') AS Field5
FROM Split_Fields
```

I have looked through SO but couldnt find anything on splitting the data the way I need. Please someone help me with this. I am really stuck on this.

I have successfully added '|' as delimiters to specify where a new row begins as proposed by Sean. I am afraid with the limited data I have I may not be able to do more. Here is the new sample data.

```
---- Sample data
    CREATE TABLE TEST1
    (
        ID varchar(20), 
        FIELD varchar(max)
    );

    INSERT INTO TEST1 (ID, FIELD)
    VALUES 
    ('ERIC','BUILT;1995/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;OZ C1|BUILT;2010/PROPERTY;Condo/TYPE;F4|BUILT;2010/PROPERTY;Condo/TYPE;F9|'),
    ('ERIC','BUILT;1996/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;OZ C1|'),
    ('ERIC','BUILT;1997/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;OZ C1|'),
    ('ERIC','BUILT;2011/PROPERTY;Condo/TYPE;F4|BUILT;2015/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;C5|');
```

Simran

Comment: While you _could_ do this in SQL Server, your life might be much easier if you instead just fix your data source so that you start out with all your data in separate columns.

Comment: What a nightmarish mess of data. You have a whole EAV table crammed into a single column. And you don't even have delimiters to specify where a new row begins. Unless you fix the data you are in for a long and painful road of unraveling this.

Comment: @SeanLange please have a look at the new data sample. I have added '|' as a row delimiter

Comment: Still a complete nightmare to work with but let me see what I can do. Regardless, the best path would be to fix the source of this and get something normalized instead. This violates 1NF by having delimited data. But it is even worse by having multiple levels of delimited data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the aid of a CROSS APPLY (or two) and a little XML

**Example**

```
Select A.ID
      ,Built    = C.Pos1
      ,Property = C.Pos3
      ,PropType = C.Pos5
 From  Test1 A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.FIELD,'BUILT;','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
                Where B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)') is not null
             ) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos1 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos5 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[5]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(replace(B.RetVal,'/',';'),';','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID      Built   Property    PropType
ERIC    1995    House       OZ C1
ERIC    1996    House       OZ C1
ERIC    1997    House       OZ C1
ERIC    2010    Condo       F4
ERIC    2010    Condo       F9
ERIC    2011    Condo       F4
ERIC    2015    House       C5
```

Comment: what is the logic with pos3 and pos5 [3], [5]

Comment: @Simran  when we do the final parse the string looks like 1995/PROPERTY;House/TYPE;OZ C1   Pos1 is year, Pos2 is ignored, Pos3 is the Property value, Pos4 is ignored, Pos5 is the Type Value

Comment: @Simran Take a peek at my tvf-Parse-Row() here.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075137/sql-server-split-string-to-row/41075500#41075500

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments this data structure is horrific. This is going to require string splitting multiple times. I am using Jeff Moden's splitter which is my go to splitter because it returns the ordinal position of the string which most other splitters (including the string_split function from MS). You can find it here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ If you don't like that one you can use string_split if you are on 2017 or you can find several other excellent splitters here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

One thing I had to do was remove the trailing delimiter from your data because a trailing delimiter means you will get an empty row. I also needed to use ROW_NUMBER to generate a unique value since each row in your original data indicates a whole collection of information. This is needed so you have something to use for grouping when doing conditional aggregation. I broke this into a couple of ctes to help illustrate the path used here. You will notice I had to use a string splitter once to isolate each "row" of data in the delimited string. Then use it again to separate the "columns" from the "rows" for each row in your table.

Again, refactoring the source data to a normalized structure would be the first and best choice. But here is some sql to return what you stated you want.

```
with MyRows as
(
    select *
        , RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by ID) --Need a unique value to use for grouping later
    from test1 t
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(left(t.FIELD, len(t.FIELD) - 1), '|') s1
)
, MyValueGroups as
(
    select r.ID
        , r.Item as TestBedItem
        , r.RowNum
        , v.*
    from MyRows r
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(r.Item, '/') v
)

select ID
    , BUILT = max(case when ItemNumber = 1 then substring(Item, charindex(';', Item) + 1, len(Item)) end) 
    , PROPERTY = max(case when ItemNumber = 2 then substring(Item, charindex(';', Item) + 1, len(Item)) end) 
    , TYPE = max(case when ItemNumber = 3 then substring(Item, charindex(';', Item) + 1, len(Item)) end) 
from MyValueGroups
group by ID
    , RowNum
```

Here is what that returns. Seems to match your desired output correctly.

```
ID      BUILT   PROPERTY   TYPE
----    -----   --------   -----
ERIC    1995    House      OZ C1
ERIC    2010    Condo      F4
ERIC    2010    Condo      F9
ERIC    1996    House      OZ C1
ERIC    1997    House      OZ C1
ERIC    2011    Condo      F4
ERIC    2015    House      C5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split it horizontally with your query, and then [UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017) that to get the vertical results you want.